# Menubar not added in a java split pane

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jmenubar, splitpane

I have written a small test program which creates a split pane in which one of the pane's is a text area. I have added a meubar and menuitems to the pane but i donot see them in the gui that is created.

Could anyone pls point out what the wrong thing did i do over here in the below program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;


//SplitPaneDemo itself is not a visible component.
public class SplitPaneDemo extends JFrame
                          implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea ta;
    private JMenuBar menuB;
        private JMenu dbM;
        private JMenuItem cnadb,bsmdb,cdmdb;
     private JLabel picture;


    private JSplitPane splitPane;
    public SplitPaneDemo() {

        ta = new JTextArea(); //textarea
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
                 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke )
                 {

                 int code = ke.getKeyCode();
                 int modifiers = ke.getModifiers();
                 if(code == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && modifiers == KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK)
                 {
                  System.out.println("cmd in table:");
           }
                }
                });

        JScrollPane taPane = new JScrollPane(ta);
        picture = new JLabel();
        picture.setFont(picture.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
        picture.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JScrollPane pictureScrollPane = new JScrollPane(picture);

        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                                   taPane, pictureScrollPane);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(450);

        //Provide minimum sizes for the two components in the split pane.
        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 100);
        taPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
        pictureScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);

        //Provide a preferred size for the split pane.
        splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));

              menuB = new JMenuBar(); //menubar
        dbM = new JMenu("DB"); //file menu
            cnadb = new JMenuItem("CNA");
            bsmdb = new JMenuItem("BSM");
            cdmdb = new JMenuItem("CDM");
            setJMenuBar(menuB);
            menuB.add(dbM);
            dbM.add(cnadb);
            dbM.add(bsmdb);
            dbM.add(cdmdb);
            cnadb.addActionListener(this);
            bsmdb.addActionListener(this);
            cdmdb.addActionListener(this);
            setVisible(true);
    }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
    }
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    }

    public JSplitPane getSplitPane() {
        return splitPane;
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SplitPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SplitPaneDemo splitPaneDemo = new SplitPaneDemo();
        frame.getContentPane().add(splitPaneDemo.getSplitPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You add the `JMenuBar` in your `SplitPaneDemo` class, but when you actually call createAndShowGUI, you make a new `JFrame` and only add the `SplitPane` to it with the call to `getSplitPane`. This new frame has no knowledge of the menu bar.

If you are extending `JFrame` in `SplitPaneDemo`, why not use that to make the frame for your gui?

Comment: Unfortunately I am a novice in java. Could you pls eloberate more?

Comment: Well, you are making a new class that extends JFrame and has a splitpane and menubar added to it. But then, instead of using that class you created, you make a new JFrame with no knowledge of any of that content. You then proceed to add only the splitpane to your new frame.

Comment: So you'll want to use the SplitPaneDemo as your frame for this gui. However, based on your code, I strongly advise you to read this tutorial on swing ui's before proceeding. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/